# How do I present an 'unfulfilled' degree on my cv for PhD/internship applications?

Tags: masters, application, cv

I currently completed a 9-month master's course at a UK university. Due to the academic intensity, I was not able to fulfill a passing grade for my course. However, the examiners allowed me to resit my exams next year, so if I can pass my failed units, I will still be able to pass the course and complete the degree requirements. As I am an international student, I will need to apply for a visa to come back and resit the exams, so currently, **it is expected, but not guaranteed that I can complete my degree next year**.

At the moment, I am thinking about applying for potential internships and Ph.D. programs. My question is how do I present my master's experience on my CV? The way I'm thinking is something like

> 2022-2023 [Course Name][University Name]

under the education section, without including the classification. Is this a reasonable option? Should I add another sentence to indicate the units I have completed, or add a note like

> Coursework Completed: 2023, Degree Expected: 2024

to show I have not fully completed the degree requirement?

For the internship I am applying for, the eligibility says

> Candidates may apply up to one year after the completion of a bachelor's, master's, or doctorate degree.

I do fulfill the bachelor's degree requirement (graduated in 2022 but slightly exceeded 12 months from now), but not sure if my master's experience could be presented in a way that doesn't hurt my application.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need something more like: program, dates, (in progress). For the internship, the note is not intending to be only for those who have completed degrees, but for those who are in school or have recently completed. So being in process of a masters would be fine.

Comment: @Dawn Thank you!

Comment: I usually see "expected completion date" in the date area for degrees not yet completed.

Comment: @Scott Seidman Thanks, is it reasonable to write 'coursework completed in 2023, expected graduation date in 2024' to indicate I am able to work for the internship full time?

Comment: @IGY - I can comment on how this is often shown in resumes and cv's, but have no creds to say what would or would not enable you to work full time.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it short:

2022-now [Course Name][University Name] (expected length: *n* years)

In the *now* is implied all that you are saying: you did not yet complete the course, you are aiming at completing it, you cannot guarantee if and when.

To make it even more obvious, write in the one-sentence CV header "currently enrolled in Master course ...". You are applying for an internship. It is reasonable to expect you are still completing your formation.

Comment: Thanks so much!